# Choice of storage and caching

Tags: c++, caching, storage

I hope the title is chosen well enough to ask this question.

*Feel free to edit if not and please accept my apologies.*

I am currently laying out an application that is interacting with the web.

**Explanation of the basic flow of the program:**

The user is entering a UserID into my program, which is then used to access multiple xml-files over the web:

http://example.org/user/userid/?xml=1

This file contains several ID's of products the user owns in a DRM-System. This list is then used to access stats and informations about the users interaction with the product:

http://example.org/user/appid/stats/?xml=1

This also contains links to various images which are specific to that application. And those may change at any time and need to be downloaded for display in the app.

This is where the horror starts, at least for me :D.

**1.) How do I store that information on the PC of the user?**

I thought about using a directory for the userid, then subfolders with the appid to cache images and the xml-files to load them on demand. I also thought about using a zipfile while using the same structure.

Or would one rather use a local db like sqlite for that?

Average Number of Applications might be around ~100-300 and stats and images per app from basically 5-700.

**2.) When should I refresh the content?**

The bad thing is, the website from where this data is downloaded, or rather the xmls, do not contain any timestamps when it was refreshed/changed the last time. So I would need to hash all the files and compare them in the moment the user is accessing that data, which can take an inifite amount of time, because it is webbased. Okay, there are timeouts, but I would need to block the access to the content until the data is either downloaded and processed or the timeout occurs. In both cases, the application would not be accessible for a short or maybe even long time and I want to avoid that.  I *could* let the user do the refresh manually when he needs it, but then I hoped there are some better methods for that.

Especially with the above mentioned numbers of apps and stuff.

Thanks for reading and all of that and please feel free to ask if I forgot to explain something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's probably worth using a DB since it saves you messing around with file formats for structured data. Remember to delete and rebuild it from time to time (or make sure old stuff is thoroughly removed and compact it from time to time, but it's probably easier to start again, since it's just a cache).
2. If the web service gives you no clues when to reload, then you'll just have to decide for yourself, but do be sure to check the HTTP headers for any caching instructions as well as the XML data[*]. Decide a reasonable staleness for data (the amount of time a user spends staring at the results is a *absolute minimum*, since they'll see results that stale no matter what you do). Whenever you download anything, record what date/time you downloaded it. Flush old data from the cache.

To prevent long delays refreshing data, you could:

- visually indicate that the data is stale, but display it anyway and replace it once you've refreshed.
- allow staler data when the user has a lot of stuff visible, than you do when they're just looking at a small amount of stuff. So, you'll "do nothing" while waiting for a small amount of stuff, but not while waiting for a large amount of stuff.
- run a background task that does nothing other than expiring old stuff out of the cache and reloading it. The main app always displays the best available, however old that is.

Or some combination of tactics.

[*] Come to think of it, if the web server is providing reasonable caching instructions, then it might be simplest to forget about any sort of storage or caching in your app. Just grab the XML files and display them, but grab them via a caching web proxy that you've integrated into your app. I don't know what proxies make this easy - you can compile Squid yourself (of course), but I don't know whether you can link it into another app without modifying it yourself.